# Proper align li elements on a row

Tags: html, css, calendar

I want to create my own calendar using css ul's and li's. Most calendars I have seen on the web use this way better than a table(don't know why is that). I have created some basic layout of the calendar, but seem to have a problem with aligning the day titles on top of the calendar. I am new to css so please be gentle with me. I know I could get one ready, but I like learning by doing and asking. So here is my code and the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ce4h4/)

```
<div id="calendar-month">
    <ul class="title">
        <div class="days-title">
            <li>Mon</li>
            <li>Tue</li>
            <li>Wen</li>
            <li>Thu</li>
            <li>Fri</li>
            <li>Sat</li>
            <li>Sun</li>
        </div>
    </ul>
    <div class="days">
        <ul class="days-item">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li>
                <span class="day-label">1</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="day-label">2</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="day-label">3</span>                    
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="day-label">4</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="day-label">5</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="day-label">6</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="day-label">7</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="day-label">8</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="day-label">9</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="day-label">10</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="day-label">11</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="day-label">12</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="day-label">13</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="day-label">14</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="day-label">15</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="day-label">16</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="day-label">17</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="day-label">18</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="day-label">19</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="day-label">20</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="day-label">21</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="day-label">22</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="day-label">23</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="day-label">24</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="day-label">25</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="day-label">26</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="day-label">27</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="day-label">28</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="day-label">29</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="day-label">30</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="day-label"></span>
            </li>               
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css

```
* {
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#calendar-month{
    margin:auto;
    width: 600px;
    height: 480px;
    background-color:#C2CCD1
}

.title {
    margin:auto;
}

.title .days-title li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left:0.5em;
    padding-right:0.5em;    
}

.days{
    margin:auto;
    width:600px;
    height:475px;

}

#calendar-month .days-item li{
    list-style: none;
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    width:70px;
    height:86px;
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin-left:4px;
    padding-left:8px;
    margin-bottom:2px;  
}

.day-label{
    float:right;
    padding-right: 7px;
    padding-top: 2px;
}
```

It migth not be the right way, maybe you could offer me a better way to understand paddings and margins or how to group them more properly. No it's not homework or anything else :), just getting inot design small step at a time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you haven't applied the same properties to `.title .days-title li` as you have `#calendar-month .days-item li`. Specifically, `width`, `padding` and `margin`.

Add these to `.title .days-title li`:

```
width: 70px;
margin-left: 4px;
padding-left: 8px;
```

***[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ce4h4/1/)***

Comment: And one last question.Could you make it clear for me?
.class1 .class2 li means apply css to all li's that are children of an element with class2 which by turn is children of an element with class1? Is this what those kind of chains mean? Any good tutorial that can make really clear the path to specific elements in css?

Comment: `.class1 .class2 li` means an `li` that is a descendent of `class2` which is turn a descendent of `class1`.

Answer (score 0):

If your days have a fixed width of 70px, why not add the CSS:

```
.days-title li{
    width:64px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gwLr9/)

Comment: Thnak you! you are all very helpfull!